QGIS - SpatiaLite - SQLite string manipulations (position/replace)
I have two layers :

Layer 1: ESPECES_HABITATS_ATTRIBUTS, with fields 'espece' (containing
unique values) and 'distance' (an integer).

Layer 2: ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY, with fields 'ESPECE' (a multiselect
value relation allowing multiple values) and 'Lval' (also a
multiselect value-relation widget).


I want to update 'Lval' in ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY when 'distance' is modified in ESPECES_HABITATS_ATTRIBUTS.
Here's how it should work:
1) First, count the number of commas located before NEW.espece in the field 'ESPECE'.
2) Then, starting from the same comma position, replace the content located between the nth comma and the next one with the content of NEW.distance.
Example :

"ESPECE" (table ESPECES_HABITATS_ATTRIBUTS) = 'Spec1, Spec2, Spec3,
Spec4, Spec5, Spec6'
"espece" (table ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY) = 'Spec4'
"distance" = 100 Lval = '50, 100, 50, 45, 25, 65'
'Spec4' is located between the third and the fourth ','.  So, the
content of the chain located between the third and the fourth "," (=
'45') must be replaced.
Result : Lval = '50, 100, 50, 100, 25, 65'

I made many attempts to locate the specific comma I need, but so far, none of them have been successful.

The problem of string replacement (positioned within a list) can be solved in SQLite, but one has to use a workaround, making use of the table-valued functions that are made part of the SQLite-core since version 3.38.0.
Not being versed in the creation and use of triggers, this answer is incomplete in relation to the question, but focuses entirely on the part where localized string replacement is concerned. This might be relevant in creating the final solution to the original question, but is for now explained by use of an example query (with explanations below):
WITH especes_poly AS (
  SELECT 1 AS my_id
  , 'spec1, spec2, spec3, spec4, spec5, spec6' AS especes
  , '50, 100, 50, 45, 25, 65' AS lval
), especes_attr (espece, distance) AS (VALUES
  ('spec1',  50),
  ('spec2', 100),
  ('spec3',  50),
  ('spec4', 100), -- new distance for 'spec4'
  ('spec5',  25),
  ('spec6',  65)
), esp AS (
  SELECT my_id
  , json('["' || replace(especes, ', ', '","') || '"]') AS especes
  , json('[' || replace(lval, ', ', ',') || ']') AS lval
  FROM especes_poly
), esp_dump AS (
  SELECT my_id, s.key, s.value AS espece, l.value AS lval
  FROM esp, json_each(esp.especes) AS s JOIN json_each(esp.lval) AS l USING (key)
)
SELECT DISTINCT my_id
, group_concat(espece, ', ') OVER my_win AS especes
, group_concat(a.distance, ', ') OVER my_win AS lval
FROM esp_dump AS d
JOIN especes_attr AS a USING (espece)
WINDOW my_win AS (
  PARTITION BY my_id 
  ORDER BY key 
  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
)

In this query the following steps are taken:

CTE "especes_poly" creates a single test record, with a dummy id column named "my_id", a comma separated string named "especes" and a comma seperated string with distances named "lval" (containing the to-be-updated lval '45' for 'spec4')
CTE "especes_attr" creates a table of unique values for "espece" with updated values for "distance"
CTE "esp" transforms the two "string lists" into JSON-arrays, as follows:
For the list of species the comma separator is replaced by a string containing a double quote plus a comma plus another double quote, using the replace function. Before the first item and after the last item the respective opening and closing double quotes are added, and the whole is encapsulated between square brackets. This should create a valid JSON array: by passing it to the json() function the result will indeed be a valid JSON array or it will give an error
the list of distances in "lval" is also transformed into a JSON array, but as it contains integers no double quotes are needed
CTE "esp_dump" in a way performs an unnest operation such as available in PostgreSQL, but is absent in SQLite, and does so for both JSON arrays. Table-valued functions such as `json_each' can, in SQLite, only be used in the FROM tree
The output of `json_each' contains a number of columns, of which "value" returns the value of the array element, and "key" contains the index of that element within the array (1-based). Under the assumption that both arrays have the same length, the two 'unnested' arrays are joined on the basis of their respective keys to ensure equal ordinal positions
the main SELECT statement at the end then joins the previous result with the table (CTE) with the updated distances for the given species. The assumption in this query example is that every species in "especes_poly" has a corresponding record in "especes_attr"
in order to reassemble the string lists, the aggregate function group_concat is used, but in this case as a window function to ensure correct re-ordering the species and their distances
as the window (named "my_win") is used twice, it is declared once after the FROM-tree but re-used in the SELECT-list, partitioning by the temporal key called "id" in this example and ordering by column "key" that contains the ordering within the original string lists. This will normally produce sequentially growing string lists for each partition but by specifying the entire range within each group (using ROWS) each resulting record will have the same list containing the total number of species (and distances) for that group
to remove duplicate records, the keyword DISTINCT is added to the SELECT statement.

Note that in more recent versions of SQLite (newer than used here) the use of window functions for ordered re-aggregations may no longer be necessary. It seems to become possible to use something like string_agg(espece, ', ' ORDER BY key) in the more usual way in conjunction with a GROUP BY on the key column(s).
Please note also that this query may be created as a Virtual Layer in Qgis. In that case the CTEs "especes_poly" and "especes_attr" are not needed, and CTE "esp" can directly access table "ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY", replacing the example key column "my_id" with all the relevant columns (including "geometry", but excluding "especes" and "lval" as they are created anew) from the original table.
If that same list of columns is used as replacement for columns "my_id" in CTE "esp_dump" and in the main SELECT statement (which should join on "ESPECES_HABITATS_ATTRIBUTS" in place of the CTE "espece_attr") as well as in the PARTITION section in window definition "my_win", the result will be a copy of the original table "ESPECES_HABITATS_POLY" but with updated values in the "lval" list.
This Virtual Layer can then be exported as an update version of that table. Perhaps this procedure may serve as a temporary solution to the problem as originally described.

Thank you for all these explanations. I haven't been able to implement it as I originally expected. I'm continuing to work on it whenever I have time. Recently, the solution I tested involved recalculating the entire fields instead of modifying the strings directly. This approach rewrite the string each time I need to make a change.
